# Cassandra READ operations latency dependency of WRITE operations

Tags: performance, cassandra, latency

I'm testing Cassandra performance in the case of simultaneous read and writes operations.

Latency for `READ` operations is important for me, WRITES usually are done once per day, so I'm investigating if the `WRITE` operations would affect `READ` operations latency.

I have a table of `10_000` records which I `READ` from application at 50 RPS. For example, the latency is 10ms, `REQUEST_SERIAL_CONSISTENCY` and `REQUEST_CONSISTENCY` is `QUORUM` for `READ` operations.

Query for `READs` is: `SELECT * from table where id = X`

Simultaneously I run another application which insert same records to table (with same ids, so in fact it is `UPDATE` operations), the `REQUEST_SERIAL_CONSISTENCY` and `REQUEST_CONSISTENCY` is `ALL` for `WRITE` operations. In several threads, I load my Cassandra cluster with batches of INSERT queries size of 60 queries in batch.

Query for `WRITEs` is: `INSERT into table values(id,..) where id = X;`

What I expect it is the latency increasing for READ operations when WRITES is enabled. But latency is stable in general besides random spikes like:

[image]

Why hasn't latency been changed, was it wrong to expect uniform latency increase?
What about these spikes, can it be connected with MemTable flushes to disk? I can see them in statistic:

```
nodetool tpstats
MemtableFlushWriter          0      0       4272      0       0
```

Info of my cluster:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;

 keyspace_name      | durable_writes | replication
--------------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        system_auth |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}
      system_schema |           True |                             {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
 system_distributed |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3'}
             system |           True |                             {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.LocalStrategy'}
             search |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}
      system_traces |           True | {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '2'}
```

Answer (score 1):

With 10000 records, I do not expect much change in latency. Latency can get hit due to lot of factor. It could be that Cassandra is doing I/O for compactions, repairs and that could hit your latency even when no write is done. So I assume random spikes you are seeing is because of some compactions running in background. One more thing, when you say you are inserting records in batch of 60, please dont use Cassandra batch for inserting records as they will be slow.

Comment: Thanks, table has 33_000_000 rows, but I operate only 10_000 rows in order to increase READ hit rate of rows which have been updated by INSERT in order to create contention.
But finally yep, I figured out that I have MutageStage operations/compactions and memtable flush operations which all affect latency, and by reducing the RPS of WRITE operation I can smooth out the READ latency spikes significantly.